# When a row has a MAX value then get it a string value of "Yes"?

Tags: sql, group-by, max, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I think this should be a quick one, but how do I get to identify a MAX value of a table and give it a string label "Yes"?

I know there is a case statement in this but just need some direction.

Example

```
ID      Amount   Max
110      1000     
111      1000
112      2000    Yes
113      1000
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: oracle, mysql, sql-server...?

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when amount = max(amount) over () then 'Yes' end
from mytable t
```

Some RDBMS do not like the empty `over()` clause, in which case you can use `rank()` instead:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when rank() over(order by amount desc) = 1 then 'Yes' end
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=55bd2ba7a52f620780dd1829c06d303d)**:

```
 id | amount | case
--: | -----: | :---
110 |   1000 | null
111 |   1000 | null
112 |   2000 | Yes 
113 |   1000 | null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub-query if DBMS doesn't support window functions :

```
select t.*, 
      (case when t.amount = (select max(t1.amount) from table t1) then 'Yes' else '' end) as Max
from table t;
```

You can eliminate `else` clause in case if you want `null` instead.